# eachWithIndex loop is unstable

Tags: java, loops, grails, groovy, each

I have code like below

```
           Map data = result?.data as Map
           data.eachWithIndex { dataItem, idx ->
                if (dataItem) {log.info dataItem}}
```

The problem I have here is the code portion of `data.eachWithIndex { dataItem, idx ->`. This works perfectly sometimes and throw below error sometime

> 2018-10-15 10:07:31,569 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR
>   listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job:
>   Grails Job Message: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature
>   of method: java.util.ArrayList.entrySet() is applicable for argument
>   types: () values: [] Possible solutions: toSet(), toSet(),
>   intersect(java.lang.Iterable), intersect(java.lang.Iterable),
>   intersect(java.util.Collection), every()

I had checked that in all the case, `data` always had a same value and it was never been null.

[image: data value]

Please kindly advice what could be the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure data is allways a map? It seems sometimes it's a List

Comment: Its a map that contain arraylists

Comment: in your screenshot I can see data is a List and the first element is a Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**result?.data** is instance of list (look at the data class after "as Map" operation it becomes ArrayList1_groovyProxy...)
You can iterate through list(and build the map if you need):

```
Map data = [:]
result?.data?.eachWithIndex { dataItem, idx ->
   if (dataItem) {
      log.info dataItem
      data[idx] = dataItem
   }
}
```

If this happends time to time - probably your **result?.data** already comes sometimes as List and sometimes as Map